# Auto incrementing delta table id with START INCREMENT by

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

When I try to generate a default increment it works just fine, but adding START WITH, INCREMENT BY throws an error. I'm using DB 11.3 so it should be supported, pic with error attached[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets are used to identify optional values - took me a few tries to get the syntax right...

```sql
%sql CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE products (
  product_id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 1),
  product_type STRING,
  sales BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO products (product_type, sales)
VALUES ("Batteries", 150000);
INSERT INTO products (product_type, sales)
VALUES ("lAPTOP", 100000);
```

[image: Sample Output]

Hope it helps...